# Uniform convergence of sequence of functions gn and fn

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

Given two functions
$$f_n (x)= x\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right), x \in \mathbb{R}, n \in \mathbb{N}$$
And
$$g_n (x)= \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} ,& x \space  \text{is irrational} \space \text{or} \space  x=0, n \in \mathbb{N}\\ b+\frac{1}{n}, & x\in \mathbb{Q}, \text{say, }x=\frac{a}{b},b>0,n \in \mathbb{N}\end{cases}$$

It is said that these two sequence of functions are uniformly convergent in any bounded interval.  If I use the definition i get pointwise convergent for the first sequence like:
$$|x\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)- x|=|\frac{x}{n}|<\epsilon$$
Here N depends on x also. I don't get how this sequence of functions is uniformly convergent in any bounded interval.  I tried graphically and couldn't able to grasp it.

For second sequence $g_n$ i don't even understand the convergence in any bounded interval.
Can anyone help me see through these functions

Source of problem: $Tom M Apostol's$ Mathematical analysis pg. No. 247

Comment: The definition for $g_n$ seems incorrect and not well defined. Could you perhaps correct the definition?

Comment: I've made some corrections for easy understanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your functions are what I think you mean, then the pointwise limits  should be $f(x)=x$ and

$$ g(x)= \begin{cases} 0  &,x\notin \mathbb{Q} \; \text{or} \; x=0 \\ q &, x=\frac{p}{q}\in \mathbb{Q}, \gcd(p,q)=1  \end{cases}. $$

In which case, you would get that $\vert f_n(x)-f(x)\vert= \frac{1}{n} \vert x \vert$ and $\vert g_n(x)-g(x)\vert= \frac{1}{n}$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

By definition, $h_n$ converges uniformly to $h$ on $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ if $M_n:= \underset{x\in A}{\sup} \vert h_n(x)-h(x)\vert \overset{n\to \infty}{\to} 0$.

If $A= [-K,K]$, can you see why these $M_n$ must converge to $0$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you!! great explanation.

Comment: @LakshmiPriya You're welcome. I'm glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

to proof that a sequence converges uniformly you need to proof that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}sup|{f_n}(x)-f(x)|=0$$
so for the first function let the interval be [a,b]
$$sup_{[a,b]}|f_n(x)-x|=sup_{[a,b]}|\frac{x}{n}|$$
let t=max{|a|,|b|} (because $|\frac xn|$ reaches its maximum at |a| or |b|)
$$sup_{[a,b]}|\frac{x}{n}|=\frac tn$$
thus:
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac tn =0$$
therefor $f_n$ is uniformly convergent in any bounded interval $$$$
but if the interval is not bounded the function won't converge because
$$sup_{[a,\infty[}|\frac tn|=\infty$$
so n does depend on x but if x is bounded it does not matter